# CSS Transitions Using :target

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set up a system where I can control which div is displayed on the screen at one time. I have two divs and both should be displayed using the buttons; "page1" and "page2".

I started by giving each div an absolute position and a 100% width. I used a CSS transform to move both DIVs back 100% so they are offscreen.

I then wanted to use :target to take the transform off the selected div.

```
#page1{
position:absolute;  
text-align:center;
background:blue;
float:left;
width:100%;
transform:translateX(-100%);
}

#page2{
position:absolute;
text-align:center;
background:red;
float:left;
width:100%;
transform:translateX(-100%);
}

:target{
transform:translateX(0);
}
```

I know that when I turn the set the transform to 0 manually in the CSS, the DIV correctly displays. What happens is that when I click the link, nothing happens. Am I missing something here? Thanks

The full HTML/CSS file is here:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.controlBar{
text-align:center;
float:left;
width:100%;
background-color:green;
}

.pageContain{
float:left;
width:100%;
}

#page1{
position:absolute;  
text-align:center;
background:blue;
float:left;
width:100%;
transform:translateX(-100%);
}

#page2{
position:absolute;
text-align:center;
background:red;
float:left;
width:100%;
transform:translateX(-100%);
}

:target{
transform:translateX(0);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="controlBar">
    <h1>Control Bar</h1>
    <a href="#page1">Page 1</a>
    <a href="#page2">Page 2</a>
</div>
<div class="pageContain">
    <div id="page1">
            <h1>page 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="page2">
        <h1>page 2</h1>
    </div>  
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#page1:target,#page2:target{
   transform:translateX(0);
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FjeaE/

Comment: Thanks! All answers were completely valid except... the mix up between classes and ids were completely my error when copoy and pasting out of date code in to this thread. My problem was solved by using this CSS. @Robert McKee - May I ask why this worked? I don't really understand why this was required. I thought :target would work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your target `<div>`s need to have their IDs set so that they are actually targeted by the hash links.

i.e.

```
<div class="page1" id="page1">
    </h1>page 1</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I must apologise. The HTML I posted was a bit out of date due to some careless undoing and copy & pasting. The HTML actually uses IDs and not classes. I have updated the post to reflect this. Can anyone see any other reasons?

Answer (score 1):

If this is the actual code you're using, then your `transform` styles are never being applied in the first place. Your css is using `.page1` and `.page2` classes but your divs do not have those classes. Either switch your CSS to use `#page1` and `#page2` or give them the appropriate classes. Example:

```
<div class="pageContain">
    <div id="page1" class="page1">
            <h1>page 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="page2" class="page2">
        <h1>page 2</h1>
    </div>  
</div>
```

With these changes, the existing CSS you supplied works for me in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Your targets are utilizing the `id` attribute, but your CSS targets the class attribute:

```
#page1{
position:absolute;  
text-align:center;
background:blue;
float:left;
width:100%;
transform:translateX(-100%);
}

#page2{
position:absolute;
text-align:center;
background:red;
float:left;
width:100%;
transform:translateX(-100%);
}
```